# Python - Calculating frequency of products with respect to given query

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we are given 100 rows in a DataFrame with two columns. One is `QUERY` and other is `PRODUCT`. Both `QUERY` values and `PRODUCT` values can be repeating. like

```
Sr.No     QUERY  PRODUCT
    1    mobile  samsung
    2    mobile     sony
    3    mobile  samsung 
    4    laptop  samsung
    5    laptop     sony
```

Output should be

```
Sr.No     QUERY  PRODUCT  FREQUENCY
    1    mobile  samsung          2
    2    mobile     sony          1
    3    mobile  samsung          2
    4    laptop  samsung          1
    5    laptop     sony          1
```

Please note that duplicate values should not be omitted. 
How can we do this in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['FREQUENCY'] = df.groupby(['QUERY', 'PRODUCT'])['PRODUCT'].transform('size')
print (df)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
   Sr.No   QUERY  PRODUCT  FREQUENCY
0    1.0  mobile  samsung          2
1    2.0  mobile     sony          1
2    3.0  mobile  samsung          2
3    4.0  laptop  samsung          1
4    5.0  laptop     sony          1
```

Comment: I voted your answer but then it is showing : vote cast by those whose reputation is less than 15 is recorded but not displayed. I am new here btw.

Comment: I know it, you need more reputation. But you can click to `accept` mark bellow `0`, then you get `2` points.